# How to make a GtkButton fully invisible

Tags: css, gtk

I have a grid of buttons in which it is easier for me to make some buttons invisible then not creating them. They have no function and are only placeholder. They have a styleclass attached to them called `transparent`. I was mostly able to hide them but there is still a line around them left that is not fully transparent. It kinda looks like the shadow of the button or something. I tried hiding them with the following CSS:

```
.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}
```

How can I hide that last bit of the buttons? They are ToggleButtons. Not sure if that is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I am using GTK3 I looked at the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk4/stable/ch38s04.html) for GTK4 and there I found the right property. It was indeed a shadow and it can be removed with: `box-shadow: none;`

My solution now looks like:

```
.transparent {
  background: transparent;
  outline-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.transparent {
    opacity: 0;
}
```